# jQuery return var assigned to a plugin

Tags: jquery

Why am I not able to do something like this:

```
var $el = $(".sortable").sortable({
    placeholder: "placeholder",
    tolerance: "pointer",
    handle: ".handle",

});
```

Than call it like:

```
$(document).on('click', '.action', function() {
    $.post("index.php", function(data) {
        $el
    });
});
```

rather than:

```
$(document).on('click', '.action', function() {
    $.post("index.php", function(data) {
        $(".sortable").sortable({
            placeholder: "placeholder",
            tolerance: "pointer",
            handle: ".handle"
        });
    });
});
```

Is there another way to call sortable just using one line of code, or does everything needs to be wrapped in function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var foo = function(){
      $(".sortable").sortable({
         placeholder: "placeholder",
         tolerance: "pointer",
         handle: ".handle",
      });
}
```

then just do

```
$(document).on('click', '.action', function() {
    $.post("index.php", function(data) {
        foo();
    });
});
```